# What is msr primask?

Tags: gcc, iar, msr

I migrated a IAR project into Eclipse with IAR plugin. Then I wanted to switch from IAR compiler to GCC. And when I tried to compile I got this error:

> Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr primask,r3'

What does this mean? What is `msr primask`? Can this be fixed under GCC?

Comment: What MCU are you using? Also, you should probably show the code giving the error.

Comment: I don't know what part of the code... The compiler is just saying `\AppData\Local\Temp\ccH3cmLT.s:1083 Error: ...`. And MCU is `STM32F401`

Comment: STM32F401 seems to be Cortex-M4 core MCU. And `.s` files are assembler files. `msr primask` is for setting priority mask register. My guess is that you have IAR assembler code that must be ported to GCC, or you are using possibly compiler provided helper functions (such as `__set_PRIMASK`) directly or indirectly in your code.

Comment: Also, since file seems to be in temp folder, my another uneducated guess is that this is file that compiler automatically generates (maybe part of  startup code?). As such, you should go through what each IAR compiler option you have used or not used does.

Comment: msr is a assembly instruction and primask is a register. Have a look in the Cortex-M4 Generic user guide.